How do I make a numbered list in adobe after effects?
I need to make an animation with a numbered list. So that the squares with the text "Task 1, task 2 ..." move to the left and the first one disappears from the left, and then the next movement. Is it possible to do this somehow, or is it only manually copied and duplicated?
(P. S. I know that there is a repeater and I attached a screenshot with it. But it does not hang on the text, is it possible to somehow make a structure out of a square shape and text so that after throwing a repeater on top, moreover, somehow using an expression in the text to change the number depending on which copy it is?)


Can you add a clear step by step explanation of what you expect to see in each box at each time?

You can increment the number in each text layer based on its position in the comp's layer list using the "index" function. Like this:
"task \r" + index

Make a box for your first text, parent it to your text, duplicate both, then make sure all the text layers are at the top of your comp list, etc:

